# Modify an array in redux with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

im having trouble eliminating an item from an array of a shopping cart. the array consist in components each with it own delete button. when i press it i want to delete that specific componen from the array. Can someone please help? Ty.

```
case actionTypes.SHOP_DELETE_PRODUCT: {
        return {
            orders:[
            ...state.orders.slice(0, action.payload),
            ...state.orders.slice(action.payload + 1)
            ]
        };
    }
const deleteProduct = (index) => ({
type: actionTypes.SHOP_DELETE_PRODUCT,
payload: {
  index
}
```

});

```
deleteProductFunc(index){
  this.props.deleteProduct(index);
```

}

Comment: `action.payload` is the index of the item you want to remove?

Comment: why not use `.filter()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The payload you are using is an object with an index property.  Your reducer needs to reach into the payload to get the index property of payload:

```
case actionTypes.SHOP_DELETE_PRODUCT: {
  return {
     orders:[
       ...state.orders.slice(0, action.payload.index),
       ...state.orders.slice(action.payload.index + 1)
       ]
  };
}
```

An alternative solution would be to just use the index as the payload:

```
const deleteProduct = (index) => ({
    type: actionTypes.SHOP_DELETE_PRODUCT,
    payload: index
});
```